# Font Family 'Helvetica' is not loaded properly by using X-spreadsheet library

Tags: css, fonts

I have used x-spreadsheet library [X-spreadsheet library](https://github.com/myliang/x-spreadsheet) to display table.
But font 'Helvetica' does not apply on text.
[WithIframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nBjb.png)  [WithoutIframe1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Aadi.png) [WithoutIframe2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci1T7.png)
I have tried to add only font 'Helvetica neun'.
Add the url [Helvetica font url](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica:400) to get font.
Try to modify in xspreadsheet.css file, remove the other fonts.

```css
.x-spreadsheet {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Roboto, 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Actual output must display 'Helvetica' font.[enter link description here](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica:400)

Comment: Do you have the font Helvetica on your machine (only macs ship with it)? Are you loading it from the font foundry? Also, its only the third font so if either of them exists before Helvetica those will be applied. Also, its 'Helvetica Neue' (as in 'new' in German).

Comment: Yes, I have Helvetica font on my local machine.

Comment: But if i load it with local html page it shows properly. [LocalFile]:(https://app.box.com/s/hz9dswrh4zrdqy0wgkuferafya0iiea7)

Comment: You are showing us screenshots and not your actual code (apart from a brief CSS snippet which... should work? Hard to say without any context). If the font exists on your machine, calling Helvetica should simply work. I also can't believe there is a `gstatic` version of Helvetica, as Helvetica is a very expensive font that google definitely won't host for free. Also, is it of _resolute_ importance you have this font? It can use fallbacks. Anyhow, post more of your code or I'm afraid we won't be able to help.

Comment: Create a minimal, reproducable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I am not trudging through 10000 lines of _your_ code to see where a font isn't working, sorry.

Comment: Hello dear, css file: https://app.box.com/s/kj0qqklai4rn4v4d38dek3e75ao1qsj7, js file: https://app.box.com/s/58wwfqtstcm8hwf18wsvyysbj5wlkv6s and the third one x-spreadsheet.js is library.

Comment: i have try to use HelveticaNeue-Medium.woff font in replacement of HelveticaWorld-Regular.ttf. But it effect in source-sans-pro font. can you explain this ?